# Resolving $16^x+4^{x+1}-3=0$ without completing the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I managed to solve this for $x$ by completing the square and using the properties of logarithms:

$$16^x+4^{x+1}-3=0$$

However, I was wondering if it's possible to resolve this without completing the square and simply using the properties of logarithms?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to render math correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can note that $16^x=(4^2)^x=(4^x)^2$ and $4^{x+1}=4\cdot4^x$, so the equation becomes $$(4^x)^2+4\cdot4^x-3=0.$$ Let $t=4^x$. Then we have $t^2+4t-3=0$ where its solutions are $t_1=\sqrt{7}-2$, $t_2=-2-\sqrt{7}$. Since $t_2<0$ we don't have solution there; but for $t_1$ yes: $$4^x=\sqrt{7}-2\implies\boxed{x=\log_4(\sqrt{7}-2)}.$$